# Appropriate base type for simply typed lambda calculus

Tags: functional-programming, language-design, type-systems, lambda-calculus

Given the following hypothetical programming language:

- Intended for practical programming
- A simply typed lambda calculus (STLC)
- All objects are functions, based on Church encodings

I am aware that making *everything* a function means a STLC with no base types, which is impossible.

I.e. this language would require an object or set of objects which are not functions.

What would be an appropriate base type, preserving as much as possible, a 'pure' Church encoding basis?

What other flaws would such a language design have? (I'm aware that performance of programming with Church encodings, naively implemented, would be disastrous)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm writing this question, I'm thinking of the following idea:

- A `World` type, inhabited by a `World` object, which represents all objects outside of the program.
- A library of functions taking and returning `World`s, as a basic I/O library.

To avoid using a `World` twice, which would be unreasonable, the language would either have to incorporate linear or uniqueness types, or the implementation would have to limit access to the raw `World` to library functions which are known to use it safely (i.e. an `IO` monad).